# ros2 not found after ros-humble-ros-gz install

Tags: gazebo, ros2, ros-humble, ignition-fortress

I recently created a fresh virtual machine of Ubuntu 22.04 with UTM.

I installed Ignition Fortress and ROS Humble with the following command: `sudo apt-get install ros-humble-ros-gz`.

I then sourced the ros setup script with `source /opt/ros/humble/setup.zsh` in my `zsh` terminal.

**I am following this [tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Advanced/Simulators/Gazebo/Gazebo.html) and can run `ign gazebo` which opens gazebo. But `ros2` returns `ros2: command not found`. What am I missing?**

After sourcing the setup script, I am also missing environment variables such as `$ROS_DISTRO`. I checked this by running `printenv | grep -i ROS`.